# Quadric equation-physics

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{[(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)-2i\omega\gamma]^2}{[(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+4\gamma^2\omega^2]^2}=\frac{1}{[(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+4\gamma^2\omega^2]}$$

I don't understand how can I get to that solution. Any hint will be very thankful.
The denominator for that fraction it can be write like adjoint but after that I will remain with a quadric equation and it won't be the same as the solution.

Comment: Assuming that you want to solve the equation above.  Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  Suppose that $z^2$ is a positive real number.  Show that $z\in\mathbb{R}$.  If you want to prove that two sides of the equation are equal, then good luck.  They are NOT equal except at very few values of $\gamma$ and $\omega$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that on the numerator of the LHS of the equation, the [...]$^2$ operation is actually taking the modulus squared. That is, $|a+bi|^2 = a^2+b^2$.

Work it out. The conclusion is trivial after you note that.

Complex modulus is the notion of "length" in the complex plane (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html)

Comment: and this is a PERFECT end for a 'workaholic' day. thank you so much for your answer, this really helped me.